# What do the module icons mean in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

was not able to commit the module with 'cup' icon.
Also, was curious to know what icons mean.

[image: module icons in Android Studio]

Answer (score 10):

So far as i know, first icon (blue cup) is pure java library. the second icon is phone/tablet module and the third one is android library module.

You can try with Studio-File-New-New Module.

Comment: Could you post a source that confirms this?

Comment: @BenjaminSarkis I don't have the source of idea, sorry. It comes by creating all kinds of module  and compare the icons.

Comment: Where do we change the module type? all files seem to be the same

Answer (score 1):

You can see the differences in the Android [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) about modules

[image]